# MySQL: Selecting several foreign key fields on a single record

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

In MySQL (InnoDB), I have created two related tables belonging to a historical character list:

```
characters:
-----------------------------
character_id (PK):    int
name:                 varchar
birthplace:           varchar
birthplace_checking:  int
birthdate:            date
birthdate_checking:   int
------------------------------

checking:
------------------------------
checking_id (PK):     int
checktype:            varchar 
------------------------------
```

where 'birthplace_checking' and 'birthdate_checking' are foreign keys referring to 'checking_id', and 'checktype' should contain informative data such as 'Unknown', 'Documentally proven', 'Speculative' and so.

What I want to achieve is to execute a SELECT statement upon 'characters' so that '*_checking' int values are replaced by their respective 'checktype' texts (which could be different, of course).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to join to 'checking' twice as shown below:

```
select  c.name
    ,   c.birthplace
    ,   bplace.checktype
    ,   c.birthdate
    ,   bdate.checktype
from    characters c
join    checking   bplace
            on c.birthplace_checking = bplace.checking_id
join    checking   bdate
            on c.birthdate_checking = bdate.checking_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, a more compact version should be:

```
select  c.name
    ,   c.birthplace
    ,   bplace.checktype
    ,   c.birthdate
    ,   bdate.checktype
from    characters c, checking bplace, checking bdate
where   c.birthplace_checking = bplace.checking_id
  and   c.birthdate_checking  = bdate.checking_id
```